# Tkinter! Simulate pop-out window

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help on this. I'm just started to learn Tkinter and I have some difficulties to do this:

Image: Main window with a new window

[image: Image: Main window with a new window]

Basically, what I want is to do is to create a frame in the main window (root or master) that pop-out initially. This frame will contain labels and buttons; besides, it will be above other labels and buttons. Similar to the image I posted. I tried to achieve this by creating a new window but the new window comes with title, minimize, maximize and close button which it is something I do not want. I want to achieve I similar result like the image I posted. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can call ``.overrideredirect(True)`` on a window to get rid of the standard decorations.  I'm not seeing any easy way to get it centered over another window, however.

Comment: Is this to be a floating window that users can move and resize, or a window embedded within the root window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need a floating window, you can just create a frame and use `place` to place it in the center of the window.

Here's a basic example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Popout(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="black", padx=10, pady=10)
        title = tk.Label(self, text="How to play", font=("Helvetica", 16), anchor="w",
                         background="black", foreground="white")
        instructions = tk.Label(self, text="The goal of Klondike is to blah blah blah...",
                                background="black", foreground="white", anchor="w")
        cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Do not show again", highlightthickness=0,
                            background="black", foreground="white")
        oneof = tk.Label(self, text="1 of 6", background="black", foreground="white")
        close_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Close", background="black", foreground="white")
        next_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Next", background="black", foreground="white")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        title.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
        oneof.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ne")
        instructions.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew", pady=10)
        cb.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
        close_btn.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="ew", padx=10)
        next_btn.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="ew")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

p = Popout(root)
p.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")

root.mainloop()
```